# find even or odd number without modulo operator in php

Tags: php, modulo

**find even or odd number without modulo operator in php**

I am having problem to find even or odd numbers without modulo sign.
so that i cant prepare my code.

Answer (score 3):

One option is diving the number by 2. Use [`is_int`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) to check if the result is an integer. If it is, it is even. Otherwise, it is odd.

```
$number = 6;
if ( is_int( $number / 2 )  ) {
    echo "EVEN";
} else {
    echo "ODD";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[bitwise](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php):

```
$number=1;

if($number&1){
  echo $number.' is odd';
}else{
  echo $number.' is even';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use **[`subtstr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)** and a conditional that checks whether the last digit is `1`, `3`, `5`, `7` or `9`. This can be simplified with **[`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)**:

```
$number = 12345;
$last = substr($number, -1);

if (in_array($last, array(1, 3, 5, 7, 9))) {
  echo "odd";
}
else {
  echo "even";
}
```

And shrunk with a ternary:

```
echo in_array($last, array(1, 3, 5, 7, 9)) ? "odd" : "even";
```

This can be seen working **[here](https://3v4l.org/9cGQu)**.